# File Picker for Xpages

Tags: javascript, xpages

For my Xpages application, I need a file picker (just select a filename, no up- or download). I've looked around several hours and found no solution. Maybe its too simple?

Comment: Why do not you use FileuplodControl? in Xpages?

Comment: I've tried that, but I don't want to upload any file, just select a filename on the local machine. Like the OpenFileDialog in LotusScript.

Comment: Then you can use the java packages...

Comment: Wich package ? .... and how ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `<input type="file" id="morituri" />`. You can't *set* the file name, but you can read it. Add a presubmit listener that grabs the name and removes the input from the DOM, so it won't get submitted.